# How to compare and merge two JSON keys in Android

Tags: android, android-json

I have two JSONObjects with the same keys. But something I am getting from the API response is different from the originally expected one. That is Keys are the same but the difference in their case-sensitive. Please help me to merge that response to the originally expected one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jackson. It is very easy to use. example: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-compare-two-json-objects

Comment: yeah it is free.

Comment: Also, you can use to merge 2 json like that:                                               
JSONTest defaults = objectMapper.readValue(defaultJson, JSONTest.class);
ObjectReader updater = objectMapper.readerForUpdating(defaults);
JSONTest merged = updater.readValue(overridesJson);